# R ggplot2: Fit the XY co-ordinates within the geom_segment function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fit a list of X-Y co- ordinates within this range . Y axis= 0 to 420 and X axis = -130 to 130.
Data: 
**a** (It is extracted from a table and I used data.table package to extract the X and Y columns). So the data for "a" is below:

```
             x          y
 +         20         34
 +          9         19
 +         15         91
 +         18         36
 +         18         34
 +          4         29
 +         47         24
 +          1         19
 +         14        103
 +         -5         75
```

etc

```
ggplot(a,aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 0, xend = 130, yend =420))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 0, xend = -130, yend =420))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 0, xend = 0, yend =0))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 0, xend = 0, yend =0))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 420, xend = 0, yend =420))+
    geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 420, xend = 0, yend =420))
```

Below is the image generated:

[image]

Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. What's wrong with `xlim(c(-130, 130))`?

Comment: Title has `geom_rect` and you provide `geom_segment`

Comment: @PoGibas - This problem is from the data class of the input. See my answer.

Comment: @PoGibas corrected my question..Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the class of your data is numeric first. If the data is a character class, for example, that will cause the plot error shown.

```
a$x <- as.numeric(a$x)
a$y <- as.numeric(a$y)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(a,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 0, xend = 130, yend =420))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 0, xend = -130, yend =420))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 0, xend = 0, yend =0))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 0, xend = 0, yend =0))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = -130, y = 420, xend = 0, yend =420))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 130, y = 420, xend = 0, yend =420))
```

Output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
require(data.table)

a <- fread("x          y
            20         34
             9         19
            15         91
            18         36
            18         34
             4         29
            47         24
             1         19
            14        103
            -5         75")
```

Comment: Yes! Similar to this. But on my R studio I am not able to get the same output as you did. I am reading a CSV file using "Fread" into the object 'a' . Then I am directly accessing the values from 'a in ggplot function'.

Comment: @RohanNadagouda - In this case you'd still want the as.numeric() function. I'll replace "df" with "a" in the code above to make it easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Your Solution helped. The X-Y co ordinates were characters, but after converting to numeric. The plot was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
a <- read.table(text = "
x          y
20         34
9         19
15         91
18         36
18         34
4         29
47         24
1         19
14        103
-5         75", header = T, sep = "")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-130,130), ylim = c(0,420)) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -130, xmax = 130, ymin = 0, ymax = 420, fill = NA, color = "black")
```

Output looks as follows:
[image]